# How to change all states of certain part of child components in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

http://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/yagLLZ?editors=0010

I have `FormatModule` component which is two levels deep from `RepeatModule`. I want whenever onClick is triggers `onClick={this.props.changeFormat.bind(this)}` on the `FormatModule`, it will change all the statues for all the of `islamic` to `islamic: '09999999',`, or whichever got passed in from `changeFormat` function inside the `RepeatModule`

I heard this is the only way to manipulate state massively when its nested inside a list of components.

For now, when I click on where `onClick={this.props.changeFormat` is implemented, values are not response to the change. I wonder where is the place I missed link? Since `changeFormat` is a function that got passed in from the top parent component down to the `FormatModule`... unless its not the way to do it?

**NOTE: I need a solution that not involving Redux or Flux**

Answer (score 1):

With a help of colleague, its already fixed in my code pen: http://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/yagLLZ?editors=0010

So the issue was that:

> 1. I `bind(this)` in the wrong scope. Should only bind inside the RepeatModule
> 2. the `newFormat` state should follow the format of the original format ( in this case it was an `array` so `newFormat` should be an
>      `array` as well!

Enjoy!

(Hope whoever voted down my questions come back and learn their stuff before put others down first, especially without any reason)